# Dojo to jQuery migration

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, dojo, code-migration

I have this code:

```
dojo.declare("City", null, {
    constructor : function(cityid, cityinfo){
    }
});

dojo.declare("TPolyline", GPolyline, {
    constructor     : function(points, color){

    },
    initialize      : function(map){
});
```

What should be it's jQuery equivalent?

Comment: An explanation of what your original code does would be useful.

Comment: It's trivial inside the function bodies and nothing framework specific. I just need to know, how to define these classes  with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that jQuery provides tools for creating classes and packages out of the box. You can look to see if there is a [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins#jQuery_Extensions) that does it.

If this turns out to not be true, I would love to know the answer as well! I have used jQuery a bit but use YUI to build packages and classes.